# how can I use the dir created by withTempDir in a rule?

Tags: shake-build-system

I need to refer to the directory created by `withTempDir` by name in the Actions.  I am guessing that the current working directory is changed by `withTempDir`, and that would likely work in the simple case. However some of the Actions must do their own `(Cwd somewhere)`.

Is there a way inside an Action to get the full path name of the created temp dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`withTempDir` does not change the current directory. In general, changing the current directory (a global resource) in a multithreaded program is a very bad idea. The name of the temp directory is passed to the function given to `withTempDir`, so you can do:

`withTempDir $ \mydir -> do
    putNormal $ "Temp directory is " ++ mydir
    liftIO $ writeFile (mydir </> "test.txt") "writing out a temp file"`

I agree the docs for `withTempDir` are a bit lacking so have [raised a bug](https://github.com/ndmitchell/shake/issues/516) to improve them.